# turn their ambition/ambitions into reality/a reality

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Since 'ambition' and 'reality' can be either countable or uncountable, do I have to use them both countably like Sentence 1 or I can use one of them countably while the other one uncountably like Sentence 2? (I wrote the two sentence.)

> In some cultures, children are often told that they can turn their
> **ambition** into **a reality** if they work hard enough. (I think the two bold words are both countable here)

> In some cultures, children are often told that they can turn their
> **ambitions** into **reality** if they work hard enough. (I think I used
> 'ambition' countably but 'reality' uncountably. Is this okay?)

Comment: As [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turn+it+into+a+reality%2Cturn+it+into+reality&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for *turn it into [a] reality* shows, both versions (with/without the article) are in common use. I don't see any scope for there being any difference in meaning - it's just an arbitrary stylistic choice. People are less likely to include the (singular) article with plural *turn **them** into a reality*, but I don't see any good reason for that. Use whichever permutations you like.

Comment: ...it used to almost always be ***turn them into realities***, but lately ***turn them into a reality*** [has become equally common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turn+them+into+a+reality%2Cturn+them+into+realities&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no grammatical requirement with *turn X into Y* that x and y have the same number. The same is true of similar constructions, as with the verb **make**.

> I'm going to show you how to turn these ingredients into a cake.
>
> The book says you can make your dreams a reality.

Just thought I'd make explicit what is implicit in the comments above.